# Which of these event handlers should work to trigger a custom function on window close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay, I have the data pipeline working fine, If I map the event handler to an input click trigger it sends the data via Jquery/Ajax to the PHP processing file and that writes the data to the SQL db.

However, none of the methods I have tried to trigger the Ajax send on window/page close seem to be working. I do not want to return an alert box, however all of the examples I have found online seem to demonstrate only the use of the onbeforeunload, beforeunload, and unload events to display an alert box. They also say you can launch a custom event, but I have not found a reliable example of such an event.

What am I doing wrong guys? Here is the code. All of my attempted triggers are near the top commented out except for the latest, so you guys can see what I have already tried.

```
var formData;

$(document).ready(function() {

//$("#driver").click(function() {

//$('a[rel!=ext]').click(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
//$('form').submit(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });

//window.onbeforeunload = function() {

//jQuery(window).bind("beforeunload",function() {

//$(window).unload(function() {

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {

    var date=new Date();
    var formData = $("#testform :input[id!='card-type'][id!='paymentSelection_0']"+
    "[id!='ccSelectedRadio'][id!='card-number'][id!='card-exp-month'][id!='card-exp-year'][id!='card-cvv'][id!='billing-first-name']"+
    "[id!='billing-last-name'][id!='billing-company'][id!='billing-address1'][id!='billing-address2'][id!='billing-city']"+
    "[id!='billing-state'][id!='billing-zip'][id!='billing-phone'][id!='billing-country'][id!='useShippingRadio'][id!='useBillingRadio']"+
    "[id!='ppSelectedRadio'][name!='miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_ymixval'][name!='miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_ymixlabel']"+
    "[name!='miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_secname'][name!='paymentSelectionDS.paymentSelection_ROW0_paymentPPSelected']").serializeArray();

    $.post("jquery/process.php",
        {
            mydata: formData,
            orderSubTotal: orderSubTotal,
            orderTotal: orderTotal,
            numOfItems: numOfItems,
            items: items,
            ids: ids,
            codes: codes,
            qtys: qtys,
            price: price,
            orderTax: orderTax,
            orderShipping: orderShipping,
            appliedPromoIdList: appliedPromoIdList,
            coupon: coupon,
            storeId: storeId,
            activeShipPromotionCount: activeShipPromotionCount,
            itemImages: itemImages,
            date: date
        }
    );
});
});
```

Comment: If you want to perform ajax, it must be synchronous, otherwise it won't complete before the browser aborts it and redirects.

Answer (score 4):

Any method of attachment you've shown here is fine, as far as attaching events goes. The problem isn't your attachment approach, per se, but rather that your function performs an asynchronous task which takes "too long" to finish before the situation changes.

When a page unloads, any pending AJAX requests are cancelled. Because ajax requests are asynchronous by default, your request won't have a chance to even connect to the server before the browser cancels it.

The only route, for this use case, is to use a synchronous request. This may cause an undesired effect, though: while your request is pending, the browser interface will appear and behave as though it is "locked".

That is why an alert WILL work, because it is by nature a synchronous, "blocking" situation. The alert box effectively stops the entire browser UI to wait for input.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: I'm looking into synchronous requests, however if you have any tips they would be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't tell you anything that the MDN doesn't already say :p